# How to get selected list item in listview by using selected index

Tags: winforms

I have selected index value in Integet 'i' variable.

i have written below code to get listview selected item by index of selected item...

```
string  previtem = listView1.Items[i - 1].ToString();
```

Value of `previtem="Parent1"`

```
string currItem = listView1.Items[i].ToString();
```

Value of `curritem="Parent2"`

```
MessageBox.Show(previtem+" "+currItem);
```

But its displayed like...

```
ListViewItem :{Parent 1} ListVieItem :{Parent 2}
```

I want output only which shows strings in the PrevItem and currItem (Parent1 and Parent2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below variable assignment, then you will get your output

```
string previtem = listView1.Items[i - 1].Text.ToString(); 
string currItem = listView1.Items[i].Text.ToString();
```